# Matrix Determinant and Shoelace Formula

Tags: matrices, determinant

Is there a neat way, apart from brute force expansion, to prove that the shoelace formula (excluding constant)
$$\begin{array}|a\;&c\;&e\;&a\\b&d&f&b\end{array}$$
is equivalent to
$$\begin{array}|a-c&b-d\\a-e\;\;&b-f\end{array}$$
?

Note that the shoelace formula can be expanded as a sum of three determinants, i.e.
$$\begin{array}|a&c\\b&d\end{array}\;+\;\begin{array}|c&e\\d&f\end{array}
\;+\;\begin{array}|e&a\\f&b\end{array}$$

Comment: I do not understand... surely you are missing some symbols or you have this formatted strangely...  Is the first expression meant to be a $2\times 4$ matrix?  ...and you have this labeled as having to do with determinants... is that a determinant of a $2\times 4$ matrix?  Such a thing doesn't exist.  Otherwise, you have a $2\times 4$ matrix and are asking if it is equivalent to a $2\times 2$ matrix?

Comment: @JMoravitz - it's the Shoelace formula, excluding the constant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving the Shoelace Method at the Precalculus Level](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017/proving-the-shoelace-method-at-the-precalculus-level)

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia article [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) explains the meaning of the $2\times 4$ matrix.
It refers to twice the signed area of the triangle
with the three vertices $(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)$. However,
if we translate the triangle so that the vertex
$(a,b)$ moves to the origin, then the other two
vertices move to $(c-a,d-b),(e-a,f-b)$. Now the
determinant of the $2\times 2$ matrix they form
is twice the area of the triangle they form with
the origin. This is directly related to the magnitude
of the cross product of two vectors being twice
the area of the triangle formed by the two vectors
and the origin.

Comment: Thanks. That's a rather neat interpretation (+1). Is there a way to manipulate the matrices algebraically to arrive at the answer instead in the absence of a geometrical approach?